# Can you use Xcode Instruments with MonoMac

Tags: xcode, macos, mono, instruments, monomac

I'm developing a MonoMac application on OS X 10.7. I've noticed that Xcode has an application called Instruments that looks like it tracks a whole bunch of stuff that would be nice for doing stress testing etc. I was wondering if you can use it with a MonoMac application?

I would've thought you could, but when I tried attaching it to my app process it didnt seem to want to record.

Any tips?

Comment: Using Instruments with MonoTouch definitively works (you can find questions/answers about it here on stackoverflow). I have not tried it with MonoMac application but I don't see why it would not work (a bug report at http://bugzilla.xamarin.com would be appreciated).

Comment: oh, thats good to know. Im not sure what I cna put in the bug beyond, tried to attach to a process and it didnt start recording..

Comment: Version numbers for everything :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect not since XCode doesn't know anything about managed/mono environments.

You could very well get the performance characteristics of the JIT engine running your code.  This is inherently related, but not very easy to map into anything meaningful without the tools having direct support/knowledge of said JIT environment.